# iOS configuration profiles to change DNS settings

Tags: ios, mdm

Is it possible to change *only* the DNS settings on iOS devices with configuration profiles?

If not, I'm guessing MDM is a possible workaround. How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MDM profile check this out:
IPSec > OnDemandRules >

`<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>EvaluateConnection</string>
        <key>ActionParameters</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>DomainAction</key>
                    <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
                <key>Domains</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>example1.com</string>
                        <string>example2.com</string>
                        <string>example3.com</string>
                    </array>
                <key>RequiredDNSServers</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>mydns.com</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>`

The limitation is that the DNS request will only perform for the listed domains. Better than nothing.

UPD:
I just found that using:

```
        <key>Domains</key>
            <array>
                <string>.</string>
            </array>
```

will wildcard the filter. So you'll get all DNS requests from the device, doesn't matter what domain it is.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of functionality is not provided by the apple MDM it provides the facility which are available in iPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility)

Comment: This is not true, since MDM can push additional configurations to the device.